# AvalonDock - How to disable autohide capability for all anchorables

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, avalondock

I'm hoping to remove the "AutoHide" capability from my usage of AvalonDock. I modeled my solution after this example here: http://lostindetails.com/blog/post/AvalonDock-2.0-with-MVVM

My current thought process is that if I can remove the option from both the tab (the symbol next to the "closing X") and the context menu, users won't be able to perform a hide operation. If there is another way to accomplish the removal of the hide operation, that would work as well.

### Removing Hide From Tab and Context Menu

In the example, he is able to set the `CanClose` property on a `LayoutItem`, thus affecting any item that is displayed due to being inside the `DocumentsSource`. I would like to do the same thing, but for `CanHide` and `CanAutoHide` and have it affect Anchorables inside my `AnchorablesSource`.

Edit: I have added the line:

```
<Setter Property="dockctrl:LayoutAnchorableItem.CanHide" Value="False" />
```

which now gets me half way there. This line removes the hide ability, however it does not remove the "AutoHide" pin symbol (or the context menu option). I know the `CanAutoHide` property does exist, I'm just not sure how to set it. Here are the relevant [docs from Xceed](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock~Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutAnchorable~CanAutoHide.html)

### Current Solution

```html
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <dock:DockingManager x:Name="AvalonDockDockingManager" Grid.Row="1"
                    AllowMixedOrientation="True"
                    DataContext="{Binding DockManagerViewModel}"
                    DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}"
                    AnchorablesSource="{Binding Anchorables}" >

            <dock:DockingManager.Resources>
            </dock:DockingManager.Resources>

            <dock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type dockctrl:LayoutItem}" >
                    <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
                    <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseCommand}" />
                    <Setter Property="CanClose"  Value="{Binding Model.CanClose}" />
                    <Setter Property="dockctrl:LayoutAnchorableItem.CanHide" Value="False" />


                </Style>
            </dock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>



            <dock:DockingManager.AnchorablePaneControlStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type dockctrl:LayoutAnchorableItem}" >
                    <Setter Property="CanHide"  Value="False" />
                </Style>
            </dock:DockingManager.AnchorablePaneControlStyle>



        </dock:DockingManager>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will have to re-style some elements of AvalonDock to get rid of the AutoHide pin. Below is a sample XAML of the **AchorablePaneTitle** style taken from the [Generic.xaml](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock/blob/master/source/Components/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock/Themes/generic.xaml).
2. As alternative solution: You can also let the Pin dissappear by setting `CanAutoHide="False" and CanHide="False"` in [this sample application](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock/blob/master/source/TestApp/MainWindow.xaml#L81).

The changed XAML looks like this

```
<avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable x:Name="WinFormsWindow"
                             ContentId="WinFormsWindow"
                             Title="WinForms Window"
                             ToolTip="My WinForms Tool"
                             CanAutoHide="False"
                             CanHide="False"
                             CanClose="False" >
    <winformsIntegration:WindowsFormsHost x:Name="winFormsHost" Background="White"/>
</avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
```

This is the screenshot taken from the linked sample application above. Note the missing pin on the **Winforms Window**.
[image]

Override the AnchorablePaneTitle style to get rid of the pin defined in PART_AutoHidePin (eg.: Set `Visibility = "Collapsed"`  on it).

```
  <Style TargetType="avalonDockControls:AnchorablePaneTitle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
          <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <avalonDockControls:DropDownControlArea DropDownContextMenu="{Binding Model.Root.Manager.AnchorableContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                      DropDownContextMenuDataContext="{Binding Path=LayoutItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Model, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  ContentTemplate="{Binding Model.Root.Manager.AnchorableTitleTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding Model.Root.Manager.AnchorableTitleTemplateSelector, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
              </avalonDockControls:DropDownControlArea>

              <avalonDockControls:DropDownButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}}"
                                                 Focusable="False"
                                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                                 DropDownContextMenu="{Binding Model.Root.Manager.AnchorableContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                 DropDownContextMenuDataContext="{Binding Path=LayoutItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                 ToolTip="{x:Static avalonDockProperties:Resources.Anchorable_CxMenu_Hint}">
                <Border Background="White">
                  <Image Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/PinMenu.png">
                  </Image>
                </Border>
              </avalonDockControls:DropDownButton>

              <Button x:Name="PART_AutoHidePin"
                      Grid.Column="2"
                      Focusable="False"
                      Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                      Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                      Command="{Binding Path=LayoutItem.AutoHideCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      ToolTip="{x:Static avalonDockProperties:Resources.Anchorable_BtnAutoHide_Hint}">
                <Border Background="White">
                  <Image Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/PinAutoHide.png">
                  </Image>
                </Border>
              </Button>

              <Button x:Name="PART_HidePin"
                      Grid.Column="3"
                      Focusable="False"
                      Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                      Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                      Command="{Binding Path=LayoutItem.HideCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      ToolTip="{x:Static avalonDockProperties:Resources.Anchorable_BtnClose_Hint}">
                <Border Background="White">
                  <Image Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/PinClose.png">
                  </Image>
                </Border>
              </Button>


            </Grid>
          </Border>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Model.IsAutoHidden, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
                         Value="True">
              <Setter Property="LayoutTransform"
                      TargetName="PART_AutoHidePin">
                <Setter.Value>
                  <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Model.CanClose, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
                         Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Command"
                      TargetName="PART_HidePin"
                      Value="{Binding Path=LayoutItem.CloseCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
              <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                      TargetName="PART_HidePin"
                      Value="{x:Static avalonDockProperties:Resources.Document_Close}" />

            </DataTrigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Comment: I ended up implementing the first option and it did work for me. #2 also works, but only for applications that know what docking elements are going to be added ahead of time (so not when you are binding against an item source)